# Can we give both onTouchListener event and onClickListener on a single text view?

Tags: android, onclick, ontouchlistener

Can we give both onTouchListener event and onClickListener on a single text view...if yes can I have sample code for it..
Thanks
Ali

---

Yes thank you friends..it works!!! But there is a small issue I am using OnClick for for moving text up and dowm and OnCreateContextMenuListener for showing menu list...Problem here is if I am using OnCreateContextMenuListener for textview1 then onclick is not performing on the Textview1...Why I dont know....I need your suggestion ..thank you –

Answer (score 3):

Here you are:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textview_example);
                tv.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //YOUR CODE HERE
                    }
                });

                tv.setOnTouchListener( new OnTouchListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //YOUR CODE HERE
                        return false;
                    }
                } );
```

You have to remember that maybe a TouchEvent will be also fired when you receive a ClickEvent.

UPDATE:

I think that everything will be much more clear if you take a look at the [Input Events documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html).

Comment: Kudos on advising him about touches also firing clicks!! I'd vote up twice if I could. :)

Comment: I've not tested but I'm saying this using the login and reading the description of that listener. Updating the answer with more datail

Comment: Your answer was perfectly fine. I was simply saying congratulations and was glad to see it. :)

Comment: Yes thank you friends..it works!!!  But there is a small issue I am using OnClick for for moving text up and dowm and OnCreateContextMenuListener for showing menu list...Problem here is if I am using OnCreateContextMenuListener for textview1 then onclick is not performing on the Textview1...Why I dont know....I need your suggestion ..thank you

Comment: that's because when you click on contextMenu maybe it don't throw a onClick event :) Maybe they are 2 different events fully separated

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer,
i would like to add that `onTouchlistener` will be activated `onKeyDown()` initially and will keep on firing whenever view is touched

and `onClickListener` will be fired `onKeyUp()`

Comment: Yes thank you friends..it works!!! But there is a small issue I am using OnClick for for moving text up and dowm and OnCreateContextMenuListener for showing menu list...Problem here is if I am using OnCreateContextMenuListener for textview1 then onclick is not performing on the Textview1...Why I dont know....I need your suggestion ..thank you –